# javascript debug terminal keeps opening using powershell instead of git bash

Tags: visual-studio-code

I put the default terminal

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "GitBash": {
      "path": ["C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
      "source": "Git Bash",
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash",
```

However, Javascript debug terminal opens using powershell
[Javascript debug terminal opens using powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/421a5.png)

I need it to open using git bash. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does setting ` "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "Git Bash"` help?

Comment: Unfortunately no it didn't. Downgrading to version 1.59.1 solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue since updating to VS Code 1.60 so I downgraded to 1.59.1 and now debugger launches my default profile which in my case is "Command Prompt"
here's my settings.json file:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter": "always",
    "debug.javascript.usePreview": true,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
}
```

I think it might be worth it to disable automatic updates with this in the settings.json file:

"update.enableWindowsBackgroundUpdates": false

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me to change the Javascript debugger from PowerShell to WSL (Or to any other shell of your choice)

In VS Code, Go to File -> Preferences -> Default Settings

Then search for 'defaultProfile', and the third setting that shows up should be for selecting the default shell on Windows. Set that to Bash or WSL or whatever you need and then the Javascript Debugger will use that.